# Tone and formality of the word "loth"

Tags: word-usage, tone

On [this](http://www.economist.com/blogs/economist-explains/2016/09/economist-explains-14) Economist article, the journalist uses the word loth in the following sentence:

> (...) they are loth to do this.

Checking the definition online I found: adj. unwilling; reluctant

I get the meaning completely.

- But is this a formal, obscure word?
- Is it used orally (outside of academic or formal circles)?
- What is the tone that it expresses?

I have never come across it and was curious to understand.

Comment: It's just [another spelling of _loath_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/loth). It's not even marked _archaic_.

Comment: Not to be confused with _loathe_, which is a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Loth* is just [another spelling of *loath*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/loth). It's not even marked *archaic* in my dictionaries.